# Trying to create CloudCode but am key errors when deploying

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Cloud Code but have followed the guides and tutorials. Now I just want to try the "hello" function and want to deploy the code but am getting this error:

```
Unable to authenticate app. Please make sure your applicationId and masterKey in "config/global.json" is correct
```

I have been into my settings for the app and got the application key and the masterkey and I know that these are correct inserted in the global.json

What am I doing wrong?!?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the parse command-line tool works for me.

I try to update but parse command disappear after update using "parse update". I have to re-install using command in doc: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line. Below is for Mac.

```
curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
```